# Python v2.6 rounding up with decimals (currency)?

Tags: python

So I am very new to Python and have a question about rounding up.

```
product_price = '79.98'
subtotal = Decimal(product_price)
cal_tax = '0.0825'
tax_conv = Decimal(cal_tax)
tax_total = subtotal * tax_conv
total_tax = round(tax_total, 2)
print total_tax
self.assertEqual(total_tax, '6.60')
```

total_tax returns `6.6`, and the assert fails:

```
AssertionError: u'6.60' != 6.5999999999999996
```

I am sure there is a newbie mistake I am making. I would like for 'total_tax' in this instance to round to 6.60 passing my assertion. I would be grateful for any tips anyone has to offer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `round` on decimals, `round` returns `float`. Use `quantize`:

```
total_tax = tax_total.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
```

Then compare it with another `Decimal`:

```
self.assertEqual(total_tax, Decimal('6.60'))
```

If you want to round strictly up, quantize like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP
total_tax = tax_total.quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

Comment: Huzzah!! Thank you all for your very quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

`round` is returning a floating point number which cannot accurately represent the number `6.6`.  And then you're comparing it with a string which makes the comparison fail as well... (as strings and floats will never compare equal)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string and a floating point value.

You have two options:

1. format `total_tax` as a string as well; this will automatically round the floating point value to a required number of digits:

   ```
   self.assertEqual(format(total_tax, '.02f'), '6.60')
   ```
2. compare `total_tax` value with a floating point literal instead, but with a tolerance (since floating point is not precise):

   ```
   self.assertTrue((total_tax - 6.60) < 0.01)
   ```